# Need to fix a bootstrap vertical tab's "Previous" & "Next Button" On click of tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to have vertical tabs with forms in each tab.

I referred [this link of W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp) in which I was trying to get what I need.

I modified the code as per my requirement but stuck with "Next" or "Previous" button which should not be visible on step-1 as below when I click on tabs.

[image]

When I click on "Next" the form should save data to DB(i,e MySql) and go forward to next step.

I'm attaching the code sample, any help would greatly be appreciated since I'm battling in this past 3 days :(

```js
    function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            
            if (i == 0) {
                document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
        
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    
    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    
    
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab
    
    function showTab(n) {
      // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      x[n].style.display = "block";
      //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
      if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
      }
      if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
      }
      //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
      fixStepIndicator(n);
    }
    
    function nextPrev(n) {
      // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
      if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
      // Hide the current tab:
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      // if you have reached the end of the form...
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
      }
      // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
      showTab(currentTab);
    }
    
    function validateForm() {
      // This function deals with validation of the form fields
      var x, y, i, valid = true;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-content");
      y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
      // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "") {
          // add an "invalid" class to the field:
          y[i].className += " invalid";
          // and set the current valid status to false
          valid = false;
        }
      }
      // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    /*  if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[currentTab].className += " finish";
      }*/
      return valid; // return the valid status
    }
    
    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
      // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        var tabcontent;
        
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
      //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        tablinks[n].className += " active";
    }
```

```css
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


h1 {
    text-align: center; 
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.multi-tab {
    display: none;
}

.button-div-prev-next {
    padding: 30px;
}

.button-next-previous {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-next-previous:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.round {
    border-radius: 10%;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: none;  
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.container {
padding-top: 5%;
}

.fieldset-border {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tab {
float: left;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
width: 30%;
height: 300px;
margin-top: -1px;
margin-left: -1px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
display: block;
background-color: inherit;
color: black;
padding: 22px 16px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
outline: none;
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
float: left;
padding: 0px 12px;
/*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
width: 70%;
border-left: none;
height: auto;

}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
        
        <body>
            
            <div class="container"> 
    
    
                <fieldset class="fieldset-border"> 
            
                    <div class="tab">
             
                        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Applicant')" id="defaultOpen">Applicant / Candidat</button>
              
                        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Current school')">Current school / Ecole actuelle </button>
              
                        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Former schools')">Former schools / Ecoles précédentes</button>
           
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="Applicant" class="tabcontent">
                        <h3> Applicant </h3>
                        
                        <form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="action_page.php" class="form-content">
                                <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
                                  <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label" for="inputError">First Name</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = 'form-control'" placeholder="First Name" name="fName">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label" for="inputError">Last Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = 'form-control'" placeholder="Last Name" name="lName">
                                    </div>
                                
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
                                  <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label" for="inputError">Admission Number</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = 'form-control'" id="inputError">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            
                                
                        </form>
                        
                            
                    </div>
                
        
                    <div id="Current school" class="tabcontent">
              
                        <h3>Current School</h3>
                        
                        Step-2
              
       
                    </div>
                
        
                    <div id="Former schools" class="tabcontent">
              
                        <h3>Former School</h3>
           
                        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="button-div-prev-next" align="center">
                        <button class="button-next-previous round" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)"> Previous </button>
                        <button class="button-next-previous round" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)"> Save and Next </button>
                    </div>
                    
        
                </fieldset>
         
            
            </div>
            
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want ? is your query regarding UI or php ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `fetch()` inside of your `nextPrev()` function. Where you `document.getElementById("regForm").submit();` change it to make an ajax call async and proceed to the next view. Also, right now your code goes to the next tab fine, and I also don't see the `previous` button.

Comment: Hi Samuel,

Thanks for quick response, but when I click on the tab, the previous button comes up in the first tab itself, that where I'm confused. Can you please help to provide a code where I can get rid of that?

Comment: When I click on the second tab and later click on the first tab, the previous button comes up. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: @RaviChandra what do you mean?